# Redis StackExchange LuaScripts with parameters

Tags: redis, lua, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to use the following Lua script using C# StackExchange library:

```
private const string LuaScriptToExecute = @"
local current
current = redis.call(""incr"", KEYS[1])
if current == 1 then
    redis.call(""expire"", KEYS[1], KEYS[2])
    return 1
else
    return current
end
```

Whenever i'm evaluating the script "as a string", **it works properly**:

```
var incrementValue = await Database.ScriptEvaluateAsync(LuaScriptToExecute,
  new RedisKey[] { key, ttlInSeconds });
```

If I understand correctly, each time I invoke the `ScriptEvaluateAsync` method, the script is transmitted to the redis server which is not very effective.

To overcome this, I tried using the "prepared script" approach, by running:

```
_setCounterWithExpiryScript = LuaScript.Prepare(LuaScriptToExecute);
...
...
var incrementValue = await Database.ScriptEvaluateAsync(_setCounterWithExpiryScript,
    new[] { key, ttlInSeconds });
```

Whenever I try to use this approach, I receive the following error:

```
ERR Error running script (call to f_7c891a96328dfc3aca83aa6fb9340674b54c4442): @user_script:3: @user_script: 3: Lua redis() command arguments must be strings or integers
```

What am I doing wrong?

What is the right approach in using "prepared" LuaScripts that receive dynamic parameters?

Answer (score 2):

If I look in the [documentation](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Scripting.html): no idea.

If I look in the [unit test on github](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/5f1630e77eb3fc000dbc9de742bb7f052aeb7d1b/tests/StackExchange.Redis.Tests/Scripting.cs#L736) it looks really easy.

(by the way, is your `ttlInSeconds` really `RedisKey` and not `RedisValue`? You are accessing it thru `KEYS[2]` - shouldnt that be `ARGV[1]`? Anyway...)

It looks like you should rewrite your script to use named parameters and not arguments:

```cs
private const string LuaScriptToExecute = @"
local current
current = redis.call(""incr"", @myKey)
if current == 1 then
    redis.call(""expire"", @myKey, @ttl)
    return 1
else
    return current
end";

// We should load scripts to whole redis cluster. Even when we dont have any. 
// In that case, there will be only one EndPoint, one iteration etc...
_myScripts = _redisMultiplexer.GetEndPoints()
  .Select(endpoint => _redisMultiplexer.GetServer(endpoint))
  .Where(server => server != null)
  .Select(server => lua.Load(server))
  .ToArray();
```

Then just execute it with anonymous class as parameter:

```cs
for(var setCounterWithExpiryScript in _myScripts)
{
  var incrementValue = await Database.ScriptEvaluateAsync(
    setCounterWithExpiryScript,
    new {
      myKey: (RedisKey)key, // or new RedisKey(key) or idk
      ttl: (RedisKey)ttlInSeconds 
    }
  )// .ConfigureAwait(false); // ? ;-)

  // when ttlInSeconds is value and not key, just dont cast it to RedisKey
  /*
  var incrementValue = await 
  Database.ScriptEvaluateAsync(
    setCounterWithExpiryScript,
    new { 
      myKey: (RedisKey)key,
      ttl: ttlInSeconds 
    }
  ).ConfigureAwait(false);*/
}
```

---

**Warning:**

Please note that Redis is in full-stop mode when executing scripts. Your script looks super-easy (you sometimes save one trip to redis (when `current != 1`) so i have a feeling that this script will be counter productive in greater-then-trivial scale. Just do one or two calls from c# and dont bother with this script.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Jan's comment above is correct.

The script line that updated the key's TTL should be `redis.call(""expire"", KEYS[1], ARGV[1])`.

Regarding the issue itself, after searching for similar issues in [RedisStackExchange's Github](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis), I found that Lua scripts do not work really well in cluster mode.

Fortunately, it seems that "loading the scripts" isn't really necessary.
The `ScriptEvaluateAsync` method works properly in cluster mode and is sufficient (caching-wise).
More details can be found in the [following Github issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1816#issuecomment-1145166654).

So at the end, using `ScriptEvaluateAsync` without "preparing the script" did the job.

As a side note about Jan's comment above that this script isn't needed and can be replaced with two C# calls, it is actually quite important since this operation should be atomic [as it is a "Rate limiter" pattern](https://redis.io/commands/incr/).